# How to install Rpy2 for Python 2.6 on WINDOWS XP

Tags: python, windows, rpy2

I download the rpy2-2.2.3 , and try to : `python setup.py install` on my windows xp computer with R: 2.12.2 , Python: 2.6.1 , after copying some files, it shows below error msg. How to fix ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 441, in <module>
    [os.path.join('doc', 'source', 'rpy2_logo.png')])],
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 577, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "D:\Python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "setup.py", line 144, in finalize_options
    rversion = get_rversion(r_home)
  File "setup.py", line 186, in get_rversion
    rversion = m.groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

R: 2.12.2 , Python: 2.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Latest is rpy2-2.2.7.
2. rpy2-2.3.0beta is in fact the latest
3. No official support for Win32 (or Win64) but it might build with the latest rpy2